# How to set correct keyboard in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uitextview, uikeyboard

Some of my users have reportedly had issues with the keyboard shown for input fields (`UITextView`, `UITextField`). They are based in France and use the AZERTY keyboard rather than the QWERTY keyboard. Their iOS settings are set up the right way, with the keyboard settings set to AZERTY, region is also set correctly. In other apps, the keyboard renders with AZERTY. In my app it shows the QWERTY layout.

Is there anything I can do or might have done to cause this? My `UITextField` is set up as follows (one example, but they all follow this structure).

```
var commentTextField: UITextField = {
    let commentTextField = UITextField()
    commentTextField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    commentTextField.textColor = lightFontColor
    commentTextField.textAlignment = .left
    commentTextField.text = "Add Comment..."
    commentTextField.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 15)
    commentTextField.autocapitalizationType = .words
    return commentTextField
}()
```

I have tried to replicate this behavior in Simulator with the exact same settings but I see the AZERTY keyboard. Also, the subjects having this wrong keyboard use the latest iOS version.

Any idea what could cause this and how I can resolve it? Is it related to my app or is it something related to iOS? The subjects use older iPhone models (iPhone 5S, iPhone SE, iPhone 6) but I guess it should be related to software rather than hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Setting -> Keyboard and select the language to french. Drag the French keyboard to top and select keyboard type Azerty.

Now all your app will have default French keyboard. Or you can change keyboard type from keyboard it self.